# search bar for Google Map V2

Tags: android, google-maps, search

I'm trying out on google map on adding a search bar to it.

There isn't any error shown in both the code and logcat.
However, the programme doesn't work.
It shows the page, but when I click on "Find", it didn't show anything to me.

logcat

```
07-23 11:15:25.330: W/KeyCharacterMap(30119): No keyboard for id 0
07-23 11:15:25.330: W/KeyCharacterMap(30119): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
07-23 11:15:26.180: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=20) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(30119): (thUse=28)    cached value : gbaSupportIsPossible=false
07-23 11:15:26.180: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=20) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(30119): (thUse=28) It is impossible to support GBA now (many possible reasons: no Android Context, current client is GBA service, etc.), then it will be just usual HTTP.
07-23 11:15:26.180: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=28) - NafRequestExecutorWrapperRedirectionHandler(30119): (thUse=28)    It isn't GBA flow, redirection responses are not handled.
07-23 11:15:26.190: I/AndroidHttpClient$2(30119): executeRequestSending()   director.getClass()=class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector
07-23 11:15:26.480: I/AndroidHttpClient$2(30119): execute()   finalHttpResponse.getStatusLine()=HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
07-23 11:15:26.490: I/AndroidHttpClient$2(30119): execute()#finished
07-23 11:15:31.400: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=20) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(30119): (thUse=28)    cached value : gbaSupportIsPossible=false
07-23 11:15:31.400: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=20) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(30119): (thUse=28) It is impossible to support GBA now (many possible reasons: no Android Context, current client is GBA service, etc.), then it will be just usual HTTP.
07-23 11:15:31.400: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=28) - NafRequestExecutorWrapperRedirectionHandler(30119): (thUse=28)    It isn't GBA flow, redirection responses are not handled.
07-23 11:15:31.410: I/AndroidHttpClient$2(30119): executeRequestSending()   director.getClass()=class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector
07-23 11:15:31.830: I/AndroidHttpClient$2(30119): execute()   finalHttpResponse.getStatusLine()=HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
07-23 11:15:31.850: I/AndroidHttpClient$2(30119): execute()#finished
```

here is my coding

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends  FragmentActivity  {

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    MarkerOptions markerOptions;
    LatLng latLng;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        //SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        //Getting a referenece to the map
        googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();

        //Getting  reference to btn_find of the layout activity
        Button btn_find = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_find);

        //Defining button click event listener for the find button
        OnClickListener findClickListener = new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Getting reference to EditText to get the user input location
                EditText etLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_location);

                //Getting user input location
                String location = etLocation.getText().toString();

                if(location != null && !location.equals("")) {
                    new GeocoderTask().execute(location);

                }

            }
        };

            //Setting button click event listener for the find button
             btn_find.setOnClickListener(findClickListener);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            //Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        //An AsyncTask class for accessing the Geocoding web service
        private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask <String, Void, List <Address>> 

        {

            @Override
             protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
                //Creating an instance of Geocode class
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
                List<Address> addresses = null;
                try {
                    //Getting a max of 3 address that matches the input text
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0],3);

                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return addresses;
            }

            @Override 
            protected void onPostExecute (List<Address> addresses) {
                if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0 ){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                //Clears all the existing markers on the map
                googleMap.clear();

                //Adding markers on Google Map for each matching address
                for(int i = 0; i < addresses.size();i++){
                    Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);

                    //Creating an instance of GeoPoint to display in Google Map
                    latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(),address.getLongitude());
                    String addressText = String.format("%s,%s", address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0): "",
                            address.getCountryName());

                    markerOptions = new MarkerOptions ();
                    markerOptions.position(latLng);
                    markerOptions.title(addressText);

                    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    //Locate the first location
                    if(i==0)
                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I may know why you are not getting anything when you hit the button. It is because the String location = etLocation.getText().toString(); returns a blank string. Can you put in a log entry or a toast and see if this is what is happening?
        I am having a similar problem with EditText and shared intents over at my tread here
[Trouble sending stuff from an EditText to another activity using intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835178/trouble-sending-stuff-from-an-edittext-to-another-activity-using-intents)

Unfortunately , if this is the case I do not know how to solve your problem.